# Creating a foreign key constraint with Oracle

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, ddl

I'm trying to create a constraint between table mail.id to table disposition.mailid, here is my syntax

```
alter table disposition add foreign key (mailid) references mail(id) on cascade delete;
```

the problem is I get this error

```
alter table disposition add foreign key (mailid) references mail(id) on cascade delete
ORA-00905: missing keyword

Time: 0,002s
```

or is there any easy way to make a constraint between two table on navicat?

Comment: `on delete cascade` not `on cascade delete`

Answer (score 0):

Solution: {1} Use the keyword CONSTRAINT, {2} give the constraint a name, {3} write: ON DELETE CASCADE.  Example (Oracle 12c):

```
create table mail ( id number primary key ) ;
-- Table MAIL created.

create table disposition ( id number primary key, mailid number ) ;
-- Table DISPOSITION created.

alter table disposition 
add constraint disposition_fk 
foreign key (mailid) references mail(id) on delete cascade ;
-- Table DISPOSITION altered.
```

Testing

```
-- table MAIL: insert 5 ids 
insert into mail ( id )
select level from dual connect by level <= 5 ;

-- table DISPOSITION: mail ids 1-5 okay, 6 etc not accepted
begin
  insert into disposition ( id, mailid ) values ( 101, 1 ) ;
  insert into disposition ( id, mailid ) values ( 102, 2 ) ;
  insert into disposition ( id, mailid ) values ( 103, 3 ) ;
  insert into disposition ( id, mailid ) values ( 104, 4 ) ;
  insert into disposition ( id, mailid ) values ( 105, 5 ) ;
end ;
/
-- PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

insert into disposition ( id, mailid ) values ( 106, 6 ) ;
-- ORA-02291: integrity constraint (...DISPOSITION_FK) violated - parent key not found
```